# Text Box with changeable font

Tags: html

How to make in HTML text box with possibillity to change font like on the image below

[image]
 I was searching and I don't found, so please help me. (I'm not good at English. Sory)

Comment: Look for "wysiwyg" (What You See Is What You Get), "JavaScript" and "editor" keywords on Google. You will soon land on : http://ckeditor.com/demo

Comment: Answer below is a cool solution too.... [Demo here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/basic-example/) I didn't know about until now. Will check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Tiny MCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) - there are others available. Maybe see this [link](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/) too.

Dan